# why does my angular response interceptor not have the cookies listed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cookies

I am setting a few cookies from my node backend like so:

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', 'id=' + result.id + '; expires=' + new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1800 * 1000)).toUTCString() + '; path=/');
```

I would like to know when this expires in my Angular app, so I setup a $http response interceptor and my interceptor returns with a response property:

```
response: function(response) {

    console.log(response.headers());
    return response;
}
```

But `response.headers()` show all headers but the cookies, though I am able to see them on Chrome's Network tab. I am not setting the cookies to be httpOnly anywhere explicitly. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue.

`Set-Cookie` needs to be added to the list of allowed headers on the server.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie");
    next();
});
```

Comment: no luck. I added 'Set-Cookie', and that didn't show anything. I had to use $cookie inside the $httpProvider.interceptor to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

If the call you are making to set those cookies is an ajax request then you need to make sure you set the `withCredentials` config option to true on the $http service. See Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for more details.

Comment: no luck. i added this in the $httpProvider.defaults. don't see any change.